# Refresh body of bootstrap modal dialog after uploading something

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm creating a service where I'm changing some data in DB via bootstrap modal dialog. After uploading file I'm showing name of this in my modal dialog body. But I can not see the name of the file what I've just uploaded, I have to close dialog and then open it again, without it I'm not able to see the actual name of uploaded file.

The question is: How to refresh "modal-body" of modal dialog without closing it?

Here is my modal html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content" style="width: 535px">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Edit Event</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <div id="dialog-edit"></div>
            <div id="EditStatus"></div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my javascript:

```
tab.on("click", ".btnUpload", function (e) {

        var formData = new FormData();
        var id = $(this).closest("tr").find('#fileId').text();
        var file = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files[0];
        formData.append("id", id);
        formData.append("file", file);

        

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Events/UpdateJsionFile",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {
                if (!data.success) {

                    var res = $('<div style="color:red;">' + data.error + '</div>')
                    $('#uploadStatus').html(res);
                    
                }
                else {

                    $('#uploadStatus').html("File #1 uploaded!");
                    
                }
            }

            });


    });
```

Everything is working perfect but I have no idea how to refresh data after uploading?
Can somebody help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it like this:

first I've created a variable with file name:

```
var fileName = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files(0).name;
```

and then, after success in my ajax:

```
$('.FileUpload').html(fileName);
```

hope it will help somebody, who was looking for the same thing...